# How to open mobiscroll Numpad without using html

Tags: angular, ionic3, mobiscroll

In Angular 5, I need to open mobiscroll NumPad without using html input field. Is there any way to call numpad instance direct from the ts file using mobiscroll module?
https://demo.mobiscroll.com/angular/numpad/#

Thanks.